# Android-add value to a listview in a fragment via edittext from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

i got a problem here. As the title said, i want to update a listview in a fragment adding a value from an edittext of another fragment. My main activity is a navigation drawer. My fragment with the listview is the Fragment_hotels and the other fragment witch contains the edittext is the FragmentAddHotel. I want to add in the listview (with the hotels) a new hotel.
Can someone explain how to do that?
Code given below:

Fragment_hotels:

```
public class Fragment_hotels extends Fragment {
    public static boolean flag=false;

    public void Add(){
        Target.add("Hotel");
        Target.add("Hotel1");
        Target.add("Hotel2");
    }


    static ArrayList<String> Target = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hotels, container,false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        if (flag==false){
            this.Add();
        }       

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.mytextview,R.id.tv, Target);

        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;  
    }
}
```

And FragmentAddHotel:

```
public class FragmentAddHotel extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_hotel, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I got an edittext and a button on my FragmentAddHotel layout.
How can i get the value from edittext and add it on the listview?
Sorry if a similar question has already been answered but i am junior programmer.
Tnx in advance :)

Comment: write a method in activity and addItem(String){
Fragment_hotels reference.updateList(String);
}Fragment_hotels fragment you handle the updateList(String)
otherwise
implement listener for the Fragment_hotels and give that reference to in FragmentAddHotel and then call method for updating the listView.

Comment: can u be more specific? @KrishnaV

Answer (score 1):

To update view in class from another one you can use EventBus library here is the [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Just register you first class by adding:

EventBus.getDefault().register(this); //in your listener class that contains the listview at onCreate method.

Also implement your receiver method:

```
public void onEventMainThread(String hotelName) {
   // Add the hotelName in your Target array list and then notify your adapter by adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

To send data from your fragment just use :

EventBus.getDefault().post("edittextvalue");

Also don't forget to call :

EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);   // In your listener class onDestroy() method.

Comment: thanks for the asnwer, but i prefer an easiest way if there is one. if i get you, you telling to import a new project into my workspace?

Comment: @Kzaf  EventBus is developed to send data between two classes, and make your code structured and easy to understand. there are a lot of ways but this is the best one in my point of view

Comment: Please check this link greenrobot.github.io/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

**In YourActivity:**

```
Fragment_hotels frag_hotels;

void addItem(String item){
  frag_hotels.addItemToList(item);
}
```

**Fragment_hotels:**

```
List<String> hotelList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
void addItemToList(String item){
   hotelList.add(item);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**In FragmentAddHotel:**

```
// you should call whenever adding is need in fragment
((YourActivity)getActivity()).addItem("Your Item");
```

Through YourActivity, you can communicate each fragment.

Comment: In Fragment_hotels i already have an adapter into the OnCreateView method. What to do with it?

Comment: debugger find a problem at Activity:

  **`frag_hotels.addItemToList(item);`**